# How to implement xor gate which has n bits input, 1 bit output in the VHDL

Tags: vhdl

As title,
The code of entity like :

```
entity n_in_1_out_xor_gate is
    generic(
       bits                 : integer
    );
    port (
        n_in                : in  std_logic(bits-1 downto 0);
        xor_gate_out        : out std_logic
    ); 
end n_in_1_out_xor_gate;
```

How to implement body of code?
Does anybody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the xor statement?

Comment: Find out about `for` loops in VHDL. eg on [my company's website](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6Feu). Or, if you're using VHDL-2008, find out about _reduction operators_.

Comment: Hi: DonFusil, I know. I should use it, but this doesn't seem to suit my problem.

Comment: Hi  Matthew Taylo. That URL cannot open.

Comment: I am having problems with it. Sorry. Please try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With vhdl 2008, you can simply write:

```
xor_gate_out <= xor n_in;
```

if you're stuck with vhdl '93, all compilers I have ever used support the std_logic_misc non-standard library that contain reduction functions:

```
xor_gate_out <= xor_reduce(n_in);
```